# Hide Button After Click (With Existing Form on Page)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to hide a button (not inside form tags) after it has been clicked. Below is the existing code. All solutions I have tried either break the functionality or interfere with the form on the page.

The content between the DIV hidden-dev tags is hidden until the button near the bottom of the code is clicked. Once that button is clicked, all of the remaining content is shown to the user.

Once the content is shown, there is no use for the button "Check Availability" so I would like to hide it (especially because the submit button appears for the core form, and it is confusing to see both at the bottom of the full length page.

Here's the existing code that does everything properly (except hide the button after the click)...

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .hidden-div {
        display:none
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="reform">
        <form id="reform" action="action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="type" value="" />
            <fieldset>
                content here...
            </fieldset>

                <div class="hidden-div" id="hidden-div">

            <fieldset>
                more content here that is hidden until the button below is clicked...
            </fieldset>
        </form>
                </div>
<span style="display:block; padding-left:640px; margin-top:10px;">
<button onclick="getElementById('hidden-div').style.display = 'block'">Check Availability</button>
</span>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Change the button to :

```
<button onclick="getElementById('hidden-div').style.display = 'block'; this.style.display = 'none'">Check Availability</button>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WVJVL/1/)

Or even better, use a proper event handler by identifying the button :

```
<button id="show_button">Check Availability</button>
```

and a script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var button = document.getElementById('show_button')
    button.addEventListener('click',hideshow,false);

    function hideshow() {
        document.getElementById('hidden-div').style.display = 'block'; 
        this.style.display = 'none'
    }   
</script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WVJVL/2/)

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution. I Hide and then confirm check

onclick="return ConfirmSubmit(this);" />

```
function ConfirmSubmit(sender)
    {
        sender.disabled = true;
        var displayValue = sender.style.
        sender.style.display = 'none'

        if (confirm('Seguro que desea entregar los paquetes?')) {
            sender.disabled = false
            return true;
        }

        sender.disabled = false;
        sender.style.display = displayValue;
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using Jquery I find it a little easier and neater than inline JS sometimes.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        /* if you prefer to functionize and use onclick= rather then the .on bind
        function hide_show(){
            $(this).hide();
            $("#hidden-div").show();
        }
        */

        $(function(){
            $("#chkbtn").on('click',function() {
                $(this).hide();
                $("#hidden-div").show();
            }); 
        });
    </script>
    <style>
    .hidden-div {
        display:none
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="reform">
        <form id="reform" action="action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="type" value="" />
            <fieldset>
                content here...
            </fieldset>

                <div class="hidden-div" id="hidden-div">

            <fieldset>
                more content here that is hidden until the button below is clicked...
            </fieldset>
        </form>
                </div>
                <span style="display:block; padding-left:640px; margin-top:10px;"><button id="chkbtn">Check Availability</button></span>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS code:

```
.hide{
display:none;
}

.show{
display:block;
}
```

Html code:

```
<button onclick="block_none()">Check Availability</button>
```

Javascript Code:

```
function block_none(){
 document.getElementById('hidden-div').classList.add('show');
document.getElementById('button-id').classList.add('hide');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

Html

```
<button class="btn-plus" onclick="afficherTexte(<?php echo $u["id"]."2" ?>,event)">+</button>
```

Java script

```
function afficherTexte(id,event){
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  
  x.style.display = "block";
  event.target.style.display = "none";
}
```