# How to disable a button for the current day after a click CODEIGNITER?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is the code that I have tried. The disable button by checking the database does not seem to work. If there is another way to disable a button for a day,let me know. Thanks in advance.

Checkin and checkout are columns in the table called checktime.

```
<?php $time=date('Hi'); ?>

 <body class='wrapper'>
<?php
$curdatein = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `checktime` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(checkin, '%m%d%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m%d%Y')");
$curdateout = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `checktime` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(checkout, '%m%d%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m%d%Y')");
//echo $curdatein;
//echo $curdateout;
if (($curdatein !='') && ($curdateout !=''))
{ ?>
<a href ="<?php echo base_url("index.php/User_controller/checkintime"); ?>">
<input type='button' id='bind'value='Check IN' name='intimebtn' class='btn btn-primary btn-md' disabled >


</a>
<a href ="<?php echo base_url("index.php/User_controller/checkouttime"); ?>">
   <input type='button' id ='unbind' value='Check Out' name='outtimebtn' class='btn btn-primary btn-md' disabled ></a>



 <?php } else { ?>
 <div class="loginform">
<?php if (($time >=0800) && ($time <=1200))  {?>
<a href ="<?php echo base_url("index.php/User_controller/checkintime"); ?>">
<input type='button' id='bind'value='Check IN' name='intimebtn' class='btn btn-primary btn-md' >
<script>

   </a>
 <a href ="<?php echo base_url("index.php/User_controller/checkouttime"); ?>">
     <input type='button' id ='unbind' value='Check Out' name='outtimebtn' class='btn btn-primary btn-md' disabled ></a>


     <?php 
       }
    else if (($time >=1600) && ($time <=2100))
     { ?>
      <a href ="<?php echo base_url("index.php/User_controller/checkintime"); ?>">
     <input type='button' id='bind'value='Check IN' name='intimebtn' class='btn btn-primary btn-md'  disabled >
    </a>
    <a href ="<?php echo base_url("index.php/User_controller/checkouttime"); ?>">
        <input type='button' id ='unbind' value='Check Out' name='outtimebtn' class='btn btn-primary btn-md' onClick="this.disabled=true;" >
    </a>
       <?php
     }

     else {
?>
         <a href ="<?php echo base_url("index.php/User_controller/checkintime"); ?>">
          <input type='button' id='bind'value='Check IN' name='intimebtn' class='btn btn-primary btn-md' disabled>
           </a>
        <a href ="<?php echo base_url("index.php/User_controller/checkouttime"); ?>">
          <input type='button' id ='unbind' value='Check Out' name='outtimebtn' class='btn btn-primary btn-md' disabled >
        <?php } }?>
       </a>
        <a href ="<?php echo base_url("index.php/User_controller/getdetails"); ?>">
        <input type='button' id ='unbind' value='Get User Details' name='getDetails' class='btn btn-primary btn-md'  >


   </a>
    </div>
    </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Before performing insert in your table check if it has one record already inserted for today if so than disable your button on that basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a table and keep a record of user's click on corresponding date,

**Example**- if a user info not inserted into the table for **current date** you can set condition to display the button.

once the user click on the button the date and user id should be inserted,so when user visits again you can check if the user id exists in the table for the current date.

Check this too if it helps-[Hide Button After Click (With Existing Form on Page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903605/hide-button-after-click-with-existing-form-on-page)