# how to make a button(input type="submit") dissapeared when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want this button to be absent after it has been clicked and finish activated. The reason I'm trying to make it like this is because, before new page gets loaded if user clicks submit button twice, then two posts are made. I followed this approach, [Hide Button After Click (With Existing Form on Page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903605/hide-button-after-click-with-existing-form-on-page) but this isn't working for me some reason.

```
<form id="post_form" method="post" action="/add_post/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}

<input type="submit" id="button" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I have input `type="submit"` I need to hide this once it's clicked.

Comment: Set a class with `display:none` and add that class to the button?

Comment: @JimGarrison you mean hide button??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set Button's `display` to `none`:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
 document.getElementById('post_form').addEventListener('submit',function(){
   document.getElementById('button').style.display='none';
 },false);    
},false);
```

```html
<form id="post_form" method="post" action="/add_post/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  
 <input type="submit" id="button" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**OR**

You can even set button's attribute to `disabled`:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
 document.getElementById('post_form').addEventListener('submit',function(){
   document.getElementById('button').setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
 },false);    
},false);
```

```html
<form id="post_form" method="post" action="/add_post/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  
 <input type="submit" id="button" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**EDIT**

You can show some waiting message after hiding the submit button:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('post_form').addEventListener('submit', function() {
    document.getElementById('button').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('wait').style.display = 'block';
  }, false);
}, false);
```

```css
#wait {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="post_form" method="post" action="/add_post/" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <input type="submit" id="button" name="submit" value="submit">
  <p id='wait'>Please Wait..</p>
</form>
```

Comment: Doesn't @winixxee want the button to **disappear**, not to be **disabled**? Although they want to prevent multiple form submissions, you probably should comment asking if they are happy with this approach before answering.

Comment: @Mirabilis *I want this button to be absent after it has been clicked and finish activated.*  Doesn't it mean OP wants to hide the button?

Comment: _I want this button to be absent after it has been clicked and finish activated._ Well I thought this meant `display:none`, but I guess it isn't quite clear. Your updated answer is much better :).

Comment: True, very true. But good answers also take good commentators ;).

Comment: thank you very much, I've been trying to figure this out for hours. Is there a way to display a text "please wait" instead of just button dissapearing? like right now it's just empty but I want to display ''please wait" instead if it's possible?

Comment: you can play with the `display` property, just add a `<p>` tag with `please wait` and set its `display: none` iinitially with css, and in `submit` eventListener, play with it..

Comment: @VickyGonsalves yes it did,do you mind submitting that as a solution??

Answer (score 0):

this is the easiest way to do it with jquery, I used online jquery.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>jquery</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
 #hideme{
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: orange;
  color: black;
  border:1px solid black;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
 }

</style>

</head>

<body>

<input type="submit" id="hideme" name="submit" value="submit"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#hideme").click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
 });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

or else you can disable it after user click once like this

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>jquery</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
 #hideme{
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: orange;
  color: black;
  border:1px solid black;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
 }

</style>

</head>

<body>

<input type="submit" id="hideme" name="submit" value="submit"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#hideme").click(function(){
   $(this).css({"opacity":"0.5"}).prop('disabled',true);
 });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why use `jQuery` just to hide a button?

Comment: what is the wrong with it, just one line of code.it is easy to understand also.

Comment: I don't understand why do you want to use such a big library, when you can do it with just few lines of native javascript code?