# JavaScript with if statements and buttons

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to JavaScript, but I have some knowledge of c, and a good amount of knowledge about HTML.

My issue in this project is that I want the second button (the one that onclick should run the `firstx2` function) to become visible only after the points are 100 or more, and I'm not sure how to go about this. Also need the button to disappear after they click it. Thanks!

```js
var points = 0;
var pointMulti = 1;
function addPoints() {
    points = points + pointMulti;
    document.getElementById("pointdisplay").innerHTML = "You have " + points 
        + " points!";
}
function firstx2() {
    pointMulti *= 2;
    document.getElementById("multidisplay").innerHTML = "Your multiplier is: " + 
        pointMulti + "!"
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Click to get started!</p>
        <button onclick="addPoints()">Add points</button>
        <button onclick="firstx2">x2 Multiplier. Cost: 100</button>
        <p id="pointdisplay"></p>
        <p id="multidisplay"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might want to alter the css property. You are almost there

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903605/hide-button-after-click-with-existing-form-on-page, just check the count before you show/hide the button.

Comment: `onclick="firstx2"` in an inline handler won't run a function.

Comment: `firstx2` never runs because you `onclick` attribute isn't correct. It should be `onclick="firstx2()"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's how you do it:

1. correct the `onclick` part of the second button, like others have mentioned
2. add an id to the second button and add styles to it: `display:none;` to hide it
3. make it appear in `addPoints` (set `display:inline;`)
4. regarding disappearing, you may set `display:none;` back again

the particular implementation below works like you described: the multiply button will appear after each click on the first button when you have >=100 points (I've set initial points to 98 for quicker testing):

```js
var points = 98;
var pointMulti = 1;
function addPoints() {
    points += pointMulti;
    var pointsArea = document.getElementById("pointdisplay");
    pointsArea.innerHTML = "You have " + points + " points!";
    if(points >= 100) {
        var multiply_button = document.getElementById("btn_multiply");
        multiply_button.style.display = "inline";
    }
}
function firstx2() {
    pointMulti *= 2;
    var multiplierArea = document.getElementById("multidisplay");
    multiplierArea.innerHTML = "Your multiplier is: " + pointMulti + "!";
    var multiply_button = document.getElementById("btn_multiply");
    multiply_button.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Click to get started!</p>
        <button onclick="addPoints()">Add points</button>
        <button id="btn_multiply" onclick="firstx2()" style="display:none;">x2 Multiplier. Cost: 100</button>
        <p id="pointdisplay"></p>
        <p id="multidisplay"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you'd like the second button to be displayed only once, you should make an extra variable, something like `multiplier_got_available`, set and check it accordingly. Also, it seems that you wanted to add `points -= 100` to `firstx2`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You did not call the function properly.

changed `onclick="firstx2"` to `onclick="firstx2()"`

Also Added few edits to the logic where the score reduces by 100 when you purchase x2 Multiplier.

But the main problem was calling the function.

```js
var points = 0;
var pointMulti = 1;

function addPoints() {
  points = points + pointMulti;
  document.getElementById("pointdisplay").innerHTML = "You have " + points +
    " points!";
}

function firstx2() {
  if (points >= 10) {
    pointMulti = pointMulti * 2;
    points = points - 10;
    document.getElementById("pointdisplay").innerHTML = "You have " + points +
      " points!";
    document.getElementById("multidisplay").innerHTML = "Your multiplier is: " +
      pointMulti + "!";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Click to get started!</p>
<button onclick="addPoints()">Add points</button>
<button onclick="firstx2()">x2 Multiplier. Cost: 100</button>

<p id="pointdisplay"></p>
<p id="multidisplay"></p>
```

Comment: It's nice that you have put in the extra work for `firstx2()` but you haven't really added what the OP is asking for.... *"display only after the points are 100 or more"*

Comment: I just made a change.. Think it solves your problem.

Comment: This is very helpful, but the button still appears if you have less than 100 points. Is there a way to make it display after you get 100+ points? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, change

```
<button onclick="firstx2">x2 Multiplier. Cost: 100</button>
```

to

```
<button onclick="firstx2()">x2 Multiplier. Cost: 100</button>
```

You need the parenthesis.
Second, this should work (replace your firstx2 function with this)

```
function firstx2(){
    if(points >= 100){
        pointMulti *= 2;
        document.getElementById("multidisplay").innerHTML = "Your multiplier is: " + pointMulti + "!";
        document.getElementById("pointdisplay").innerHTML = "You have " + points;
        points -= 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful, Thanks! But I still have a few more questions. This is working now, but is there a way I can make the firstx2 button only show up after you have 100 points?

Comment: [This code](https://pastebin.com/urxq9tha) will make it so that when your points are 100 or over then the x2 button will be shown.  Otherwise, it is hidden

Comment: if you want the button to be permanently visible after the person reaches 100+ points, remove this in the add points function
`        
else{document.getElementById("x2").style.visibilty="none";
        }`

Comment: I apologize for being difficult, but when I tried to run that code, it didn't show up after I hit 100 points.